# Arquivo não aparecer para comitt no SmartGit

Tags: git

Tenho um arquivo de persistence.xml que é padrão da aplicação, porém cada desenvolvedor usa um diferente e sempre tem um que comita essa persistence sem querer. Queria saber se tem como fazer com que este arquivo mesmo alterado não apareça para ser comitado.

Comment: Não é só adicioná-lo no .gitignore?

Comment: @LINQ não conheço, mesmo usando o git local nao o gitHub da para usar o .gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já foi dito nos comentários, você pode fazer uso do [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

O `.gitignore` é um arquivo no qual você especifica outros arquivos que não devem ser *rastreados*, ou seja, que ignorará o fato de ter ou não mudanças nestes arquivos.

Se um arquivo já está no seu repositório remoto, digamos `local.config`, e você adicioná-lo ao `.gitignore`, o arquivo continuará no repositório remoto, mas qualquer mudança local feita nele não será refletida no repositório remoto pois ele não está mais sendo "rastreado".

## Padrão de busca

Cada linha do arquivo `.gitignore` especifica um caminho que segue um padrão descrito na própria [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

- Linhas vazias são ignoradas, então pode usá-las como separador entre grupos de arquivos;
- `#` no início da linha faz com que ela seja considerada um comentário;
- espaços no final da linha são ignorados;
- `!` serve para ignorar um padrão. Por exemplo, `diretório/` ignorará todos arquivos do diretório especificado, mas você pode utilizar `diretório/!arquivo` para remover o `arquivo` da lista de ignorados;
- `/` é usado como um separador de diretórios, se a barra `/` estiver no início ou meio do padrão, significa que este padrão será aplicado *em relação* ao nível de diretório que o `.gitignore` está;
- `/` no fim do padrão indica que é um padrão para diretórios, caso contrário pode ser tanto diretório como arquivo;
- `*` corresponde a qualquer caracteres com exceção da barra `/`;
- `?` corresponde a **um único** caractere qualquer, com exceção da barra `/`;
- `**/` no início corresponde a "qualquer diretório";
- `/**` no final corresponde a "tudo dentro do diretório";
- `/**/` corresponde a "zero ou mais diretórios".

## Exemplo

Dada a seguinte estrutura de arquivos e diretórios:

```
meuprojeto
├── app
│   ├── paginas
│   │   ├── .config
│   │   ├── contato.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── home.css
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │   ├── teste
│   │   ├── teste.html
│   │    
│   ├── teste
│   │   ├── .config
│   │    
│   ├── debug.log
│   ├── error.log
│   ├── error1.log
│   ├── error2.log
│   ├── error30.log
│   ├── example.log
│   ├── main.log
│
├── .config
├── .gitignore
```

Poderíamos ter o seguinte no `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignorar qualquer arquivo ou diretório chamado `teste`, note que `teste.html` não é ignorado
teste

# Ignorar todos `.log` com exceção do `example.log`
*.log
!example.log

# Parar de ignorar os arquivos `error<identificador_1digito>.log`, note que `error30.log` continuará ignorado
!error?.log

# Ignorar o `.config` que está dentro de `paginas`
/app/paginas/.config
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você cria um arquivo exemplo desse `persistence.xml`, para todos que forem desenvolver saberem que ele é necessário, para isso você pode criar um arquivo `persistence.exemple.xml`. Nele você coloca a estrutura do arquivo sem os valores. Exemplo:

```
<persistence-unit name="Hello" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value=""/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Esse arquivo você deve fazer commit dele. Agora o que já existia você precisa dizer ao git para não observa-lo mais. Você pode fazer isso com esse comando:
`git rm persistence.xml`

Agora para garantir que nenum desenvolvedor commit o arquivo dele você cria um arquivo chamado `.gitignore` na raiz do projeto e dentro dele coloque todos os arquivos que não devem ir pro git. Neste caso ficaria assim seu arquivo `.gitignore`:

```
persistence.xml
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda